# Delta Lake table - Update timestamp field to NOW() error

Tags: sql, delta-lake

I have a delta table:

```
CREATE TABLE telco.legal_queries_control_table_delta (
  legal_query_id STRING, 
  request_type STRING,
  parameters STRING,
  start_date INT,
  end_date INT,
  priority INT, 
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP,  
  status STRING,
  result STRING,
  export_path STRING
)
USING DELTA
```

With the following values:
[image]

```
-- Insert values
INSERT INTO telco.legal_queries_control_table_delta
VALUES ('20231123_000001', 'TEL', '\'12345678901\',\'23456789012\,\'34567890123\'', 20230801, 20231130, 5, NOW(), NULL, 'PENDING', NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO telco.legal_queries_control_table_delta
VALUES ('20231123_000002', 'IMEI', '\'353059051230927\',\'13428004008742\,\'357033050462274\'', 20230801, 20231130, 5, NOW(), NULL, 'PENDING', NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO telco.legal_queries_control_table_delta
VALUES ('20231123_000003', 'IMSI', '\'716060001901933\',\'716060601012679\,\'716060201872218\'', 20230801, 20231130, 5, NOW(), NULL, 'PENDING', NULL, NULL);
```

I want to update the updated_at with NOW(), but is constantly failing:

```
-- Update query
UPDATE telco.legal_queries_control_table_delta
SET status = 'RUNNING', updated_at = NOW()
WHERE legal_query_id = '20231123_000003';
```

But it fails with the following message:

```
Execute Job failed with runException. value should not be null
```

If I update to zero, works perfectly:

```
-- Working when updating to zero
UPDATE telco.legal_queries_control_table_delta
SET updated_at = 0
WHERE legal_query_id = '20231123_000003';
```

What to do? Any hints?

Comment: Please provide more information about your setup - Spark version, Delta version, etc. For me, it works find on Databricks SQL & Databricks cluster with DBR 14.0